# Why is this character black when she has white parents?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Episode "Let's Kill Hitler" we meet Mels. It later transpires that her parents are, in fact

> Rory and Amy

Since she has two white parents why would she be black? Is there a specific *in-universe* reason for this or is it just because the producers wanted certain actors to play specific characters?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may have missed the fact that the little girl we saw in the astronaut suit in *Day of the Moon* turned out to be an ***even younger River Song***, and that she regenerated at the end of that episode, changing her into a different body than the one she was born with (as regeneration always does). Apparently Mels was the result of this first regeneration.

The young River in *Day of the Moon* (who still had the body she had been born with) was white, as you'd expect for Amy and Rory's child. The ["biography" section of the TARDIS wikia article on River Song](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song) gives more details.

Comment: Ah I think my confusion was with that I thought it was her original body at that point. The little little girl would indeed match

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing to meet the (revised + re-opened) question a bit more closely.

Comment: She actually mentions the last time she regenerated.

Comment: Yeah and recall that Timelords are not limited to looks and gender.  So it's not far off that she would regenerate into a black girl.  I'm surprised we haven't had a black Doctor yet.

Answer (score 10):

She was conceived on the TARDIS as it went through a space-time vortex which gave her genetic traits similar to a time lord. This allows her to regenerate which as we know can change you from male to female; so changing skin colour doesn't seem so far-fetched.

(It is likely that the Doctor will change race* at some point in the future)

*Race defined as our races on earth not an alien race.

In "A Good Man Goes to War" her conception is revealed.

We see her regenerate in:

- "The Impossible Astronaut"/"Day of the Moon"
- "Let's Kill Hitler" -> Which is also where she loses her power.

Comment: I wonder if the Doctor could regenerate to a non-human appearance, eg Silurian? Time Lords look like humans, but so do Silurians in general (leaving aside the skin & exciting tongue action).

Comment: @NiceOrc Well they can decide their appearance given the right circumstances of death.

Comment: @CandiedMango Or [try a few on](https://youtu.be/x9eEk-S6RUc?t=1m11s).